# Front End File Upload using Vue and Winter Cms

Tags: laravel, vue.js, octobercms

I'm trying to upload images from a Vue frontend via Illuminate/Http/Request to WinterCMS.
Vue finds the file and i can console.log the File object, but I'm unsure how to get this over the api. for example I've tried

```
public function saveImage(Request $req){
$images = $req->files('images');
}
```

which doesn't work, nor does

```
public function saveImage(Request $req){
$images = $req['images'];
}
```

I'm using a controller to handle my routes eg:

```
Route::post('/saveImage', 'Author\Project\Controllers\ProductControl@saveImage');
```

I've added an attachOne relation to the plugin as usual and my form has  enctype="multipart/form-data"
I've had this problem before and got around it by converting images to base64 but this project will have quite a few images and I don't want to go down that route again.
Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send images as regular post and use regular `$request->file('images')` method in your Laravel controller.

You can use Javascript FormData object. For example;

```js
<div>
        <input type="file" @change="handleImages" multiple>
        <button @click="uploadImages">Upload!</button>
</div>
```

```js
data: () =>  ({
  images: []
}),
methods: {
  handleImages (event) {
    this.images = event.target.files
  },
  uploadImages () {
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (const i of Object.keys(this.images)) {
      formData.append('images', this.images[i])
    }
    axios.post('/saveImage', formData, {
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
    })
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your solution but I get BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Http\Request::files does not exist.

Comment: Yep it has to be ` $request->file('images')`